# Can blender combine two or more meshes of same object and make new mesh?

Tags: mesh

I have bought Agisoft Photoscan , it makes a mesh from many photos taken of an object, and applies the photos as texture so it looks like the object, but they have taken the marker tool that one uses to bring together meshes from different 'chunks' such as when you photo the object (chunk 1 set) then turn it upside down and photo it again (chunk2 set) and placed the marker tool in the pro version at 3500 euros totally out of reach of folk buying standard at 179 as Standard does all they need for basic model making, pro having all sorts of advanced stuff I simply dont need and cannot justify 3500 for a few flags ! One does have to photo undersides of objects for standard work !

So I think can I bring the meshes into blender and do what Agisoft should have done, select a few well spread out points on one and same on other and merge the meshes together then reprocess it as a new mesh ?

Also to give it scale would be good, again basic tool denied us, its only in pro.

Any videos on how this is done most welcome. Agisoft standard users would be most grateful.

Steve

Comment: "... basic tool denied..." There is nothing 'basic' about those algorithms, that's a very inaccurate description. Can Blender be used to combine meshes? - sure. Can Blender be used to automatically combine point clouds based on their features and then make meshes from them?  - no, obviously, it is not designed or meant for functionality like that.

Comment: Usually markers shouldn't be required to align photos in Photoscan, probably in your setup there weren't enough of photos or overlapping is lacking or shadows are rough or all at once. That said, Blender isn't right tool for aligning different point clouds since that's what you actually want to do. If there are problems with your Photoscan try free approach here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4NTf0hMjtY or https://www.creativeshrimp.com/free-photo-scanning-tutorial.html. It might not work so smoothly of course

Comment: Hi, nothing wrong with photos, as said, I then turned model upside down to photo its underside and consequently the surroundings and the gridded base board it sits on, if photoscan refers to that again, as it will, creates two models with one baseboard. for the sake of a few markers as per a video where a flint is brought together, I can have myself one model. I have a few thousand photos of many objects where I had to do this and just the ability to do that will save hundreds of hours of work editing out everything other than the object, time I just dont have. Can blender make me a new model

Comment: blimey limited character count for reply. I have loads of overlapping photos of the object, proper complete set correctly lit. its the simple fact the base board is different as its bound to be in set 2. What would I get if I brought together two meshes in blender ? would I edit out meshes common to both then join them at a common edge ? How are the jpg's then textured on again ? Can blender be used to complete the model as I and others havent 3500e.  Is there a video or tutorial please on whats involved. All I did was turn model upside down as you do.

Comment: Steve1, I think masking and reconstruction form multiple photo sets at once is the answer here. You could align the models manually in Blender, then retopologise them to one mesh manually and bake the textures from multiple objects to the new mesh, however, I believe you would encounter many issues during the process and I doubt that this would give you a good result while it would still require a lot of time. There are techniques to speed up the masking process and even if you have to do it manually, it does not take that much time as it seems. That's the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, if you know of any video tutorials on that please post them, as a newbie to meshing a video is so useful. Steve